# config @wordpress/scripts with webpack and postCSS features

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I using wordpress as CMS and I want to config `@wordpress/scripts` with webpack and adding PostCSS and it's plugins like: `postcss-loader`, `postcss-import`, `postcss-simple-vars`,`postcss-nested, postcss-mixins`, `autoprefixer`

as my files looks (package.json and webpack.config.js) that every thing installed and config is not having any error on vscode terminal some of the postcss features working and some other not. for example `postcss-loader`, `postcss-import`,`postcss-simple-vars`,`postcss-nested` works fine but `postcss-mixins`, `autoprefixer` not working.

For example if I create nav like this breakpoint mixin is not working and also the autoprefixer not works:

```
@define-mixin max-width-1100 {
    @media (max-width: 1100px) {
      @content;
    }
}
ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        list-style: none;

        @mixin max-width-1100 {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    }
```

```html
<ul class="index-ul">
    <li>Ali1</li>
    <li>Ali2</li>
    <li>Ali3</li>
    <li>Ali4</li>
</ul>
```

now I added my `package.json` file:

```json
{
  "name": "portfoliotheme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "start": "wp-scripts start",
    "dev": "wp-scripts start",
    "devFast": "wp-scripts start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^26.15.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "postcss-mixins": "^9.0.4",
    "postcss-nested": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1"
  }
}
```

and this is my `webpack.config.js`:

```js
//Import the orginal config from the @wordpress/scripts package
const defaultConfig = require("@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config.js");

//Import the helper to find and generate the entry points in the src directory
const { getWebpackEntryPoints } = require("@wordpress/scripts/utils/config");

const path = require('path');


//Add a new enty point by extending the webpack config
module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        ...getWebpackEntryPoints,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/scripts', 'main.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/dist'),
        filename: 'main.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [
                                    require('postcss-import'),
                                    require('postcss-simple-vars'),
                                    require('postcss-nested'),
                                    require('postcss-mixins'),
                                    require('autoprefixer'),
                                ],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

whats wrong in my code?
Any useful help would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure this is a WordPress question and not a generic PostCSS/Autoprefixer package question? Also what you've shared does not match what the official `autoprefixer` package docs say to do when using it with webpack: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer?tab=readme-ov-file#webpack I doubt this has anything to do with WordPress besides coincidence

Comment: yes, It's wordpress question because it's for the theme build and webpack must be works  configs with wp-scripts.

Comment: writing auto perfixer and the other postcss plugins writes as it must be. I read the docs. If  coding plugin is wrong it must get error in terminal or must other plugins don't work. as I said before just postcss mixins and autoprefixer dosen't work. others works great

Comment: I mention it because although you're using it in a WP context there aren't any WP libraries/APIs/packages involved, and you're probably missing the answer by constricting your search to just WordPress, especially since both post css and the two packages were added by yourself not WordPress (the autoprefixer package references a postcss config file that doesn't exist in your question )

Comment: thank you. I search about creating postcss config file and understood that when I create webpack config file, postcss config file is not necessary. However the defualt wordpress theme twentytwneyone added postcss into theme and has a postcss config but the theme itself dosen't use @wordpress/scripts. thats why I can't find any instruction about how to config with wordpress scripts package.

Comment: another thing is wordpress block editor uses @wordpress/scripts and for development it must add to plugin. how they config and bundle packages and files I confused

Comment: the documentation on how to extend the wp scripts webpack config and how it works is in the wp scripts package on github, and can be found by searching for the package on the NPM site and clicking through, there's a section explaining how it all works including a dedicated section for extending the config and examples https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/5d86605316cc339cb8f15264a3fdf395f935618f/packages/scripts/README.md#provide-your-own-webpack-config, it even mentions that it already uses postcss loader so it's highly unlikely what you've done will work

Comment: at this point, you should create the postcss config as it's both quicker and faster than trying to argue the point, the worst case scenario is that it starts working and you learn something new